# Change encoding of a single text file with powershell in one inline command

Tags: powershell, encoding

When I use the following command to create a text file from the contents of a directory powershell always encodes the output file in CRLF.

```
(Get-ChildItem .\*.tif | Format-Table Name) > tif_1.txt
```

For further processing I need to use UTF8.

I have tried to force encoding using `-Encoding "UTF8" -Force` but this create an error.

I don't want to have to open a text editor and save the file using UTF8 every time I do this. How can I either force UTF8 encoding on creation or change it with a single inline command in Powershell?

Comment: `this create an error.` - what error would that be? Show the _exact_ command in which you used the encoding switch. Please edit the question and include that information.

Comment: Why did you mention `CRLF`? Is that a requirement too so it saves with different newlines? Otherwise, just use PowerShell cmdlets that support the `-Encoding` parameter like `Add-Content`, `Set-Content` or `Out-File` instead of redirecting with `>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to use the "out file" commander

```
(Get-ChildItem .\*.tif | Format-Table Name) | out-file tif_1.txt -Encoding utf8
```

I tested everything works correctly